# Frage zur Kommasetzung vor Namen

Tags: comma

Kommt hier das eingeklammerte Komma hin:

> Okay(,) Thomas, dann machen wir es so wie gestern!

Comment: Kurze Antwort: Ja, user26147, da kommt ein Komma hin. Habe keine Quelle gefunden, die ich auch verlinken wuerde, daher habe ich keinen Link.

Answer (score 6):

§79 der [Rechtschreibregeln](http://www.rechtschreibrat.com/DOX/rfdr_regeln_inkl_Nachtraegen.pdf):

> *Anreden*, Ausrufe oder Ausdrücke einer Stellungnahme, die besonders hervorgehoben werden sollen, grenzt man mit Komma ab; *sind sie eingeschoben, so schließt man sie mit paarigem Komma ein.*

(Deinen Fall habe ich kursiv hervorgehoben)

Ausgewählter Beispielsatz:

> Hört, Kinder, doch mal zu.

Komma gehört also hin.

Comment: Eine Ergänzung: Solche Anreden sind grammatisch kein Bestandteil des Satzes in dem sie stehen. (Lässt man sie ersatzlos weg, bleibt der umgebende Satz grammatisch korrekt und behält unverändert seinen Sinn.) Schon allein deswegen sind diese Anreden von dem Satz in dem sie stehen mit Kommata abzugrenzen. Diese Anreden stehen im Nominativ (»Anredenominativ«), es wird aber auch diskutiert, ob es sich hier um Überreste eines Vokativs handelt, der sich im indoeuropäischen Ursprung der deutschen Sprache gut belegen lässt, der heute aber immer gleich gebildet wird wie der Nominativ.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Danke für die Ergänzung - Meine Ansicht dazu: Naja, *Bestandteil des Satzes* sind sie schon - sie stehen zwischen dem Satzanfang und dem Punkt ;). Der Sinn bleibt beim Weglassen m.A. nach nicht gleich - Wenn ich Kinder und Eltern oder Thomas und Fritz im Raum habe, ist schon Sinnbestandteil des Satzes, wen ich anspreche. **Notwendiger Bestandteil** sind sie nicht unbedingt.  Ich verstehe so einen Satzteil als *eingeschobene Anrede* - Und ein Einschub ist ja auch Bestandteil eines Satzes. Beim "Vokativ" bin ich bei dir.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Schon, allein, deswegen? :-)